# PHP post to url and then generate page from url

Tags: php, mysql, html

Hi im only new to php and im trying to simply post data from a link that i generated from the output of the php-mysql result. Ive been looking around for a result but most of them require using the form tag in html5. Is there a way that i could post data to the url from the hyperlink and then use this data , idealy the primary key to then display a generated page of that data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use get rather than post.

```
<a href="index.php?id=10">Link</a>
```

Then in your PHP script:

```
$primarykey = $_GET['id'];
```

(Be aware of SQL injection though).

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: That's exactly what i was after. Thank you.